# Perl Regular Expression for [^<>]

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to Perl. Please tell me what does this mean.

[^<>]{1,128}

what does this regular expression

Answer (score 9):

Let's break it down.

- `[…]`: creates a character class, which matches any of the characters (or character ranges) inside the brackets, however…
- `[^…]`: the caret inside the class negates it, meaning it will match any single character *except* the characters (or character ranges) inside the brackets, so…
- `[^<>]`: matches any single character except `<`, or `>`.
- `…{n,m}` matches between *n* and *m* repetitions of the previous character, character class, or group, so…

`[^<>]{1,128}` matches any sequence of between 1 and 128  characters other than `<`, or `>`.

**Further Reading**

- [perlre documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 1):

[http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=[^%3C%3E]{1%2C128}](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D%7B1,128%7D)

```
NODE                       EXPLANATION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[^<>]{1,128}               any character except: '<', '>' (between 1
                           and 128 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

Sometimes this can also show nice explanations:

[http://www.regexper.com/#[^%3C%3E]{1%2C128}](http://www.regexper.com/#%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D%7B1,128%7D)

But in this case not really.

Comment: Thank you very much. But does not it mean that 1 - 128 occurence of words?

Comment: No. The {} part which shows the repetition count is referencing only to the previous thing, which is a [] character list block (which length is 1). This means 1-128 occurences of the non <> characters.